# How to make numbers in a table a string that isn't solved in lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

So I'm trying to make a table with numbers in them, but also make the exact same thing but only that its a string with the numbers so doing print(table[i]) doesn't solve the problem.

```
local problems = {
  1 + 1,
  2 + 2,
}

local stringProblems = {
  "1+ 1",
  "2 + 2",
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Start with `stringProblems` and populate `problems` by evaluating each expression using `load("return "..s)()`.

Comment: I mean like how would I make the problems a string without having to make a stringProblems table?

Answer (score 4):

```
local problems = {
  1 + 1,
  2 + 2,
}
```

actually evaluates to `local problems = {2, 4}`

You cannot make

```
local stringProblems = {
  "1+ 1",
  "2 + 2",
}
```

out of it. The arithmetic expressions are evaluated when you define the table. Any information how you got those values is lost. So Lua does not know if `stringProblems` is

```
{
  "1+ 1",
  "2 + 2",
}
```

or

```
{
  "399 / 399",
  "1 + 3"
}
```

or whatever. You can only do it the other way as lhf suggested. Have the strings first.